# Check with jquery if result/echo from PHP starts with "abc"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery and ajax to submit forms without page reloading and then depending on the result (whether it is a success or an error) I print the message in two different divs. Since success and error in ajax only checks the client/server connection I echo some stuff from PHP when query succeeds and depending on that I condition what to do with the message. Jquery/ajax part looks like that (normally I use two different divs, but to simplify the example I will use alerts):

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result == 'success') {
        alert("Success!");
    } else {
        alert("There was an error.");
    }
},
```

This works perfectly, but I would like to improve its usability.

Now the question is: can I use in `if (result ==` part something like str.match? For example if there were some problems running the query I would echo in php `echo "Error: >error description here<";` Could I then somehow use `str.match(/^Error/)` in my if condition and echo the entire message?

Comment: You can yes, just treat `result` as a normal java string variable

Comment: @NaguibIhab didn't know jQuery is compatible with Java

Comment: @Naguib you didn't know that java and javascript are two entirely separate languages?

Comment: Oh no, i typed java as a shortcut for javascript.. what a terrible mistake, i should get sued :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't use string matching for this task. Use HTTP response codes - that's what they're there for! The [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) function in PHP is designed for this exact purpose:

```
<?php
if ( /* error condition */ ) {
    http_response_code(400); // "Bad request" response code
    echo 'Invalid parameters';
}
else {
    echo 'Success'; // response code is 200 (OK) by default
}
```

Then you can use jQuery's `done` and `fail` callbacks to handle the two cases separately:

```
$.ajax(url, params)
    .done(function(response) { alert('all good: ' + response); })
    .fail(function(response) { alert('error: ' + response); })
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, much better to utilize http than to try dodgy string matching client side.

Comment: I haven't thought about using http response codes as my knowledge of jquery is quite limited so it didn't even occur to me to use them. I will change the accepted answer to yours as I like it more, it has more utility. I stick with success and error though as I don't use deferred objects. Also the alert should be changed from response to response.responseText, otherwise it returns [object Object]. JSON.stringify(response) works to see the entire content of passed object. Thanks to investigating it and how to implement it in my code I learned new things about jquery so double props for that.

Comment: By changing response to response.responseText I meant it for the error part, otherwise it passes entire response with error code, etc.

Answer (score 8):

To check if the `message` starts with `Error:` you can use `indexOf`:

```
if (result.indexOf('Error:') === 0) {
    // Starts with `Error:`
}
```

`indexOf` will return the `index` starting from `0` where `Error:` is found in the `result` string.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

> The `indexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

Comment: Tom fenech is the correct answer. Not that this is incorrect, this just solves the meta problem. the real problem is the server returning a 200 on error

Comment: On the other hand there *are* web services that return error message with `200 OK` status.

Comment: Note that the op is in control of both ends of the story.  And I'm the last person to say these webservices are any good. Something with sheeps jumping of cliffs and us telling other not to do it

Answer (score 2):

to answer the 'improve' part of your question i would do some JSON.

php:

//Your code here and create an associative array like so:

```
if($errors){
  $data(
    'results'=>'errors',
    'message'=>'it failed'
  );
}else{
  $data(
    'results'=>'success',
    'message'=>'it worked'
  );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

and then your js would be somthing like:

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.results == 'success') {
        alert(result.message);
    } else if (result.results == 'errors' {
        alert(result.message);
    }
},
```

related : http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php#assoc